# Riak TS Performance Benchmark on Writing Data

Tags: python, riak

I am new to RiakTS and I am trying to compare Druid with RiakTs in IoT Area. 
I want to checkout the efficiency of writes by RiakTS before choosing the product.Hence, I started off with the below dry-run.

Data Taken: Aahrus (Data having 4.3 Million Rows)
Client Used: Python
Node: Single Independent Node.

Process went smooth. It took 6 mins to insert 4.3 Million Rows in a batch of 1 million rows.

Is this the expected performance or we can tweak it ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes, you can tweak it to get more performance. First I would note that Riak TS, while it can run as a single node, is really designed to be clustered. Adding nodes and directing writes to those nodes via a load balancer to spread the workload will increase write speed.

Some other points to consider with your current set up that will probably increase write speed a bit:

1. The Python client supports batching writes (not sure if that is the batching that you are using or not). Based on experience 100 records per batch seems to be about the optimal for performance.
2. Riak TS replicates data 3 time for HA reasons. Since you are only using a single node this replication isn't needed. When you create your table you could set the N value equal to 1. This will probably also increase your write speed.

Simple example of creating a table with an N val = 1:

```
CREATE TABLE WaterMeterData (
  customer_id       varchar   not null,
  meter_id          varchar   not null,
  time_stamp        timestamp not null,
  water_pressure    double    not null,
  gallons_per_hour  double    not null,
  total_gallons     double    not null,
  fault_condition   boolean   not null,
  fault_message     varchar,   
PRIMARY KEY(
    (quantum(time_stamp, 80, 'd')),
     time_stamp, customer_id, meter_id 
  )
)
WITH (
   n_val=1
)
```

Comment: Thanks Craig....I m running with batch option using python client. I will try this option and check the performance...